# Obtaining Dirac spectrum on unorientable manifold ($RP^n$) from orientable manifold

Tags: quantum-field-theory, dirac-equation, spinors, topology, eigenvalue

The Dirac spectrum for $S^n$ is well known along with its multiplicities. In Appendix D of https://arxiv.org/abs/1510.05663 author computes dirac spectrum of $RP^4$ from that of $S^4$. The argument author uses is that $RP^4$ has two $pin^+$ structures and applying parity condition on Dirac spectrum of $S^4$ gives the spectrum for $RP^4$. My question is

1. Why parity condition and how does it give spectrum for $RP^4$
2. Now, if I want to obtain the Dirac spectrum for $RP^n$. I know $n= 1$ has two inequivalent spin structures same as $S^1$. But how do I obtain it for $n =2, 3, 5$? I also know $RP^3$ is orientable (for odd $n$) and has 2 $pin^+$ and 2 $pin^-$ structures. But how does it affect its spectrum?

I found [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/98041/) somewhat related question, but it still doesn't answer my question.